# Mongodb query for "or" operator

Tags: mongodb

headline: finance manager ,  finance director , finance chief, finance, dba manager 
linked-in-id: 20, 30,

I need only 
Finance + (Director OR chief OR manager) using MongoDB

```
db.Profiles.find ( { $or : [ { "headline" : "/^finance {director|cheif|manager}" }] } )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
db.Profiles.find({ "headline" : {$regex:"finance\\s(chief|manager|director)" }})
```

Comment: I am not getting all the fields some fields are missing

Comment: Check whether those missing fields have more than one space b/w words. The regex matches only single space as of now. Change it to \\s+ to match more than one space. If above is not the issue, then tell us samples/values which are not matching so we can correct it.